# jQuery doesn't work unless in footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My jQuery literally will not work unless it's in the footer of my website's HTML. Why is this? I've never had this issue before, so I'm not sure what's causing it. 
My jQuery:

```
$('#trigger').click(function(e){
  var that = $(this);
  var wrap = that.parents('.wrap');
  that.toggleClass('open');
  $('.menu .sub-menu').removeClass('open');
  $('.menu').toggleClass('open');
  $(document.documentElement).toggleClass('menu-open');

   //console.log('clicked!');
  e.preventDefault();
});
var sub_parent = $(".sub-parent > a");
var sub_menu = $('.sub-menu');
sub_parent.click(function(){
  var that = $(this); //cache when you can
  var parent_menu = that.parents('.menu');
  var menu_index = parent_menu.index();
  var current_item = that.next('.sub-menu');
  //console.log(parent_menu);
  parent_menu.addClass('sub-level1-open');
  current_item.addClass('open');
});

var sub_back = $('.sub-menu--back');
sub_back.click(function(){
  var that = $(this);
  var menuIndex = that.parent().index();
  var currentItem = that.parent('.sub-menu');
  var parent_menu = that.parents('.menu');
  currentItem.removeClass('open');
  parent_menu.removeClass('sub-level1-open');
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Try wrapping it in `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Comment: Wrap your code in document-ready handler i.e. `$(function(){ //Add your code})`

Comment: @Swellar that breaks the whole jQuery, should I edit the first line?

Comment: It shouldn't 'break' it. Could you edit the code to show where you added the document.ready handler, and any error messages caused by it

Comment: @Swellar [link](https://pastebin.com/B6ThK9yi)

Comment: If that's your actual code you have several syntax errors: https://jsfiddle.net/n0r3zdbo/ Press F12 to see them in the console

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#trigger').click(function(e){
        var that = $(this);
        var wrap = that.parents('.wrap');
        that.toggleClass('open');
        $('.menu .sub-menu').removeClass('open');
        $('.menu').toggleClass('open');
        $(document.documentElement).toggleClass('menu-open');

        //console.log('clicked!');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    var sub_parent = $(".sub-parent > a");
    var sub_menu = $('.sub-menu');
    sub_parent.click(function(){
        var that = $(this); //cache when you can
        var parent_menu = that.parents('.menu');
        var menu_index = parent_menu.index();
        var current_item = that.next('.sub-menu');
        //console.log(parent_menu);
        parent_menu.addClass('sub-level1-open');
        current_item.addClass('open');
    });

    var sub_back = $('.sub-menu--back');
    sub_back.click(function(){
        var that = $(this);
        var menuIndex = that.parent().index();
        var currentItem = that.parent('.sub-menu');
        var parent_menu = that.parents('.menu');
        currentItem.removeClass('open');
        parent_menu.removeClass('sub-level1-open');
    });
});
```

You have to wrap you code with

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        // Your Code
    });
```

to make sure that the DOM is loaded before you access it.